# Interpreter["Country"] returns only South Africa as a single item list

Tags: interpreter

I am working with a list of countries that I then want to utilize `Interpreter` on for some later functionality.  For some reason, "South Africa" returns as a single item list within the list while all the other countries do not.

```
countries = {"eSwatini", "South Africa", "United States", "Canada", 
   "South Sudan"};
Interpreter["Country"][# & /@ countries]
```

[image]

I then tried to expand the dataset by looking at a list of all countries:

```
webcountries = 
  Import["https://www.dfa.ie/travel/travel-advice/a-z-list-of-\
countries/", "Data"];
countrylist = webcountries[[4]];
Interpreter["Country"][# & /@ countrylist]
```

There were a few in the list that `Interpreter` failed to work with, but interestingly, only South Africa returns as a single item list within the list.

I can't think of any other reason this would happen besides a bug.

Thoughts?

Comment: With version 11.3 on my Mac, your code produces a single-item list for all five entries.

Comment: Fascinating.  I am also running 11.3, but on Windows 10.  I exited out of everything and started fresh, but still got the same result shown in the image above.

I tried running it with the Wolfram online options (Mathematica Online, Programming Lab, Development Platform) and they all returned as a list with no countries being single-item lists.

Seems odd to have three different results from the same code.

Comment: when I execute your code on wolfram cloud through a mobile app, which I believe is running 11.3, I get a list of single items, as @BobHanlon reported.

Comment: I think Bob was saying he is getting a list of single item lists, whereas the wolfram cloud returns a straight list of Entities.  Is anyone able to duplicate my results on a similar setup (11.3 on Windows 10).

Comment: I cannot reproduce output with 11.3 on Win 10; I get a single-item list. Note that you do not need to map that function over the list `Interpreter["Country"][countries]` will do just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Edmund.  So are you saying that for you, all the country Entities are single item lists?

Comment: 10.4 and 11.3 on Linux: no brackets around South Africa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up contacting Wolfram Technical Support on this issue.  Their recommendation was that reset Mathematica to its default configuration.  I did that as outlined in this site: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464

All seems to work as expected at this point.

No idea why such a specific error would occur, but at least I have a fix for it.

Comment: More likely than not, the value was cached and incorrect somehow. You effectively deleted the cached values when you removed those directories.